# Friendly URLs when using a Record ID for dynamic content

Tags: friendly-url, seo

I've read a bit on the matter of friendly urls and I'm a little unsure as to what is better.

I currently have my website using a structure of `http://www.domain.com/page.php?id=2`

I am using the record id to determine the content of the page.  My record id's are numeric and increment for new pages added.  The content of existing pages can change completely over time.   But, still use the same record id (this is a cms so the client may do this).

The way I understand it I have two options for friendly urls:

`http://www.domain.com/page/2`

`http://www.domain.com/some-text-describing-the-page`

Now because I identify the content by the record id, I would assume the first option would make more sense.

My client seems to want option two.

After some reading I found two conflicting points.

As per Tim Berners-Lee (the architect of the WWW) he states that you want a URI which will have the potential to remain the same 2 months, 2 years, 200 years from now.  So you DO NOT want to use a page title or something similar for your pages.  If you change your pages content you are either forced to change the content and leave the URI alone, or change the URI and are stuck with dangling links.  You can read his article here (http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI)

However, a number of other people on the internet (with no know authority to me) clearly state that you need to have a descriptive yet short URI for the best SEO value.  From what I read, mostly for the purpose of backlinks and having keywords in the anchor text since people just use the link itself for the anchor text.  So having keywords in the link itself helps search engines know what the link is about without a custom title.

It seems to me the difference has to do with long term VS short term.

Am I grasping this correctly?

If I am to use a slug style URI as defined by the user, do I have to just allow my user to type in whatever they want to a field and check against the current database to see if it exist?  If so, am I supposed to anticipate static links by running a query for the know record id and then use the result to generate the url which would just be rewritten back to the format: `http://www.domain.com/page.php?id=2`?

It seems to me that would be a lot of extra overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something in the middle of those two:

```
http://www.domain.com/page/2/some-text-describing-the-page
```

or without `page`:

```
http://www.domain.com/2/some-text-describing-the-page
```

You can still get page Id from the Url, and there is a title as well! And what even more important, you're still able to get correct content, even when page title change later.

So think about situation like that: User creates a page, it receives Id=4 and it's title is `My great title`. From that information Url is generated, and is e.g. `http://www.domain.com/page/3/my-great-title`. After 2 months user changes the title to `This title is better then the last one!`. Url changes as well to `http://www.domain.com/page/3/this-title-is-better-then-the-last-one`. However, there is still `3` within the Url, so you're able to show right content!  You can also check, if the rest of Url is actual, and redirect (301 would be the best one) to new one to let search engines know, that Url changed.

Comment: Hrm, I supposed added a title would be all right if I don't make it matter.  The URIs `http://www.domain.com/page/3/title1` and `http://www.domain.com/page/3/title2` would always product the same result so I would never get a broken link, but it forces search engines to see the descriptive portion of it.  Thank you lol.  Now it's just a matter of trying to automate this process in my .htaccess nicely, shouldn't be too bad though.

Comment: Remember to add redirection from URLs with wrong titles! Or at least add rel=canonical to let search engines know, that those URLs points to the same content!

Comment: I was just thinking I would pull the content from the record id in the url and the title was simply there for aesthetic purposes.  So if a user originally has the slug title1 the url would be  `http://www.domain.com/page/3/title1` and then changes the slug to title2 for the url `http://www.domain.com/page/3/title2`  I have to write a 301 redirect for it?